# How do we simulate the circuits which have processors. Is there any way we can simulate the circuit before going to the pcb manufacturing?

Tags: pcb-design, simulation, microprocessor, hardware, ibis

I'm working on a project on which I'm using a snapdragon 410e processor.
I'm done with the circuit design since all the data is available online for designing the PCB.
But I want to simulate the whole circuits, Is there any way I can simulate these types of processors before going to the PCB design.

Comment: Functional simulation? Or simulation of specific analog behavior, like power planes and differential pairs?

Comment: In other words, what are you hoping to learn from such a simulation?

Comment: There's a big, BIG difference between doing an electrical simulation of the PCB, and doing a full up functional simulation of the board+processor+software.

Comment: For example, I want to check if the flash memory and the processor are communicating or not? Writing a basic code to test the connection. @DaveTweed

Comment: Simulation of each analog behavior, like the selected frequency of the crystal, the clock signals are generating, the behavior of the input/output pins. I want to simulate all this online or for example how we used to code in the proteus and get our microcontroller circuit verified.@Jeroen3

Comment: @SteveSh I am looking for a functional simulation, before going into PCB electrical simulation,

Comment: I am not aware of anything like your suggesting being done at my company, and we do some pretty complex boards/assemblies (big FPGAs with multiple ARM cores; multi GHz DACs and ADCs, microwave/RF circuits, etc).  We model/simulate piecemeal, do electrical/signal integrity analysis for most interfaces, timing analysis, and sometimes a WCCA (Worst Case Circuit Analysis).  But we do not simulate the entire board/assembly as a whole.

Comment: For testing things like the communication protocols implemented in software I would use sample boards together with breadboards. I dont see the necessity to use a simulation environment including the final board. What can be intresting is the simulation of EMC behaviour but I don't know what tools are available for this purpose.